# Toolbar going outside the Page in Linux Firefox not on windows

Tags: css, jsf, firefox, layout, richfaces

I am building a JSF and richfaces based web application. I have a homepage which is shown to user once he logins.

I am using `<rich:dropDownMenu>` in header inside `<rich:toolbar>`. The header is included in all the pages.

While the layout is looking perfectly fine in Windows, when the same application is run on Linux, the toolbar is going outside the page.

Each `<rich:page>` width is 800. I want the same layout in windows and Linux browser.
I tried with many possible combinations but it is still going outside the page.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for over 2 days, we figured out it was the problem with the Font which was causing the header to go outside the page in Linux.

The Linux OS was not having the font which was used in the header and hence was using default font due to which the header was stretching.

Installing required fonts on Linux did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what is the concrete reason behind the issue, however as a workaround you can wrap your `<rich:toolbar>` inside a div, i.e, `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` and set its maximum width accordingly.